# XPath concat all matches of sibling nodes

Tags: xpath, saxon, xpath-2.0

I have not found a solution in similar thread so I hope someone can help me. I have XML as follows (excerpt):

```
<root>
<identificationInfo>
<MD_DataIdentification>
<descriptiveKeywords>
            <MD_Keywords>
                <keyword>
                    <gco:CharacterString>Atmospheric conditions</gco:CharacterString>
                </keyword>
                <type>
                    <MD_KeywordTypeCode codeListValue="theme"/>
                </type>
            </MD_Keywords>
        </descriptiveKeywords>
        <descriptiveKeywords>
            <MD_Keywords>
                <keyword>
                    <gco:CharacterString>Agriculture</gco:CharacterString>
                </keyword>
                <keyword>
                    <gco:CharacterString>Biodiversity</gco:CharacterString>
                </keyword>
                <type>
                    <MD_KeywordTypeCode codeListValue="socialBenefitArea"/>
                </type>
            </MD_Keywords>
        </descriptiveKeywords>
```

What I want is to concatenate the strings of type and keyword, so that I *get a list* that looks like the following:

```
theme:Atmospheric conditions
socialBenefitArea:Agriculture
socialBenefitArea:Biodiversity
```

I have tried the following solutions (XPath 1.0 or XPath 2.0 both can be used), but always only the first match 'theme:Atmospheric conditions' is returned.

- `for $n in /*/gmd:identificationInfo/*/gmd:descriptiveKeywords/gmd:MD_Keywords return string-join(($n/gmd:type/*/@codeListValue, ':',
  $n/gmd:keyword/*/text()), '')`
- `/*/gmd:identificationInfo/*/gmd:descriptiveKeywords/gmd:MD_Keywords/gmd:keyword/concat(*/text(), ':', ../gmd:type/*/@codeListValue)`
- `//gmd:descriptiveKeywords/*/string-join((gmd:type/*/@codeListValue,
  gmd:keyword/*/text()[1]), ':')`
- `//gmd:descriptiveKeywords/*/gmd:keyword/concat(following-sibling::gmd:type/*/@codeListValue, ':', ./*/text())`

If the XPaths look correct, I am doing this in Java with `Saxon-HE 9.x`.

What I did find out is that the evaluation returns a String, not a NODESET, which I probably need to have multiple results. Which XPath would return a NODESET?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The XPath 2.0 expression `//gco:CharacterString/concat(ancestor::MD_Keywords/type/MD_KeywordTypeCode/@codeListValue, ':', .)` returns (http://xsltransform.net/6r5Gh2U) a sequence of three strings

```
theme:Atmospheric conditions
socialBenefitArea:Agriculture
socialBenefitArea:Biodiversity
```

I don't see why you ask for a node set as XPath 2.0 does not returns node sets but rather sequences of nodes or primitive values. As your result is not contained in nodes but you want to concatenate strings contained in different nodes, I don't see how nodes selected in the input would help, if you want to create new nodes then you need XSLT or XQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the confusion about strings and node-sets comes because you are using the JAXP API, which was designed for XPath 1.0 and doesn't allow you to exploit the full flexibility of XPath 2.0. If you want to return a sequence of strings from your XPath expressions, as @Martin Honnen suggests, then you will need to use the s9api API instead: this handles the full XPath 2.0 data model. You can't get around this limitation using JAXP and node-set results because XPath doesn't allow you to create new nodes (only to select existing nodes), and the strings you want do not correspond to existing nodes.

However, if you're really constrained to JAXP, then you could change the query to combine the results into a single string by using the string-join() function, with some suitable delimiter (e.g. newline), and the split it back into multiple results by tokenizing in the calling Java code.

Answer (score 0):

**Just use**:

```
/*/*/*/*/MD_Keywords/keyword/*/concat(../../type/*/@codeListValue, ': ', .)
```

---

> Which XPath would return a NODESET?

**An Xpath 3.0 expression can produce a node(-set) by using a standard function, such as** [**`parse-xml()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-parse-xml) or [**`parse-xml-fragment()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-parse-xml-fragment)